# Confirmation box (Bootbox) not appear after click submit button

Tags: javascript, php, html

Currently, a create a PHP page to update data. I use bootbox confirmation box before I click the button 'submit' to update the data to the database.

The problem is, when I click the button, it will update the data without popup the confirmation box. Below is my current code.

php

```
  <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])); ?>" method="post">
          <table class='table table-bordered' align="center" width="100%">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Requester</th>
                <th>Date Booked</th>
                <th>Purpose</th>
                <th>Factory</th>
                <th>Room</th>
                <th>Start</th>
                <th>End</th>
                <th>Remark</th>
                <th>Status</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td><?php echo $Requested_by; ?></td>
                    <?php 
                        $booked = strtotime($Book_Date);
                        $Book_Date = date("d M Y -- g:i A", $booked);
                    ?>
                <td><?php echo $Book_Date; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $Meeting_Description; ?></td>
                <td data-factory="<?php echo $Fac_ID; ?>"><?php echo $Fac_ID; ?></td>
                <td data-room="<?php echo $Room_Desc; ?>"><?php echo $Room_Desc; ?></td>
                    <?php 
                        $Start = strtotime($StartTime);
                        $StartTime = date("d M Y -- g:i A", $Start);
                    ?>
                <td><?php echo $StartTime; ?></td>
                    <?php 
                        $End = strtotime($EndTime);
                        $EndTime = date("d M Y -- g:i A", $End);
                    ?>
                <td><?php echo $EndTime; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $Remark; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $Book_Status; ?></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div><br>
    <div class="card-body double">
      <h4 class="card-title">Find Room</h4>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Factory/Permises</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $Fac_ID; ?>" disabled>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleFormControlSelect2">Room No.</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $Room_Desc; ?>" disabled>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleFormControlSelect2">Date & Time.</label>
        <div class="main" >
          <div style="float:left; width: 160px;">
            <div id="nav"></div>
          </div>
          <div style="margin-left: 160px;">                    
            <div id="dp"></div>
          </div> 
        </div>
      </div>
  </div><br>
  <div class="card-body double">
      <h4 class="card-title">Action</h4>
        <form action="update_booking.php" method="POST"> 
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Status</label>
              <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" name="Book_Status">
                <option value="Pending" <?php echo $Book_Status == 'Pending'? 'selected': '';?> >Pending</option>
                <option value="Reject" <?php echo $Book_Status == 'Reject'? 'selected': '';?> >Rejected</option>
                <option value="Approve" <?php echo $Book_Status == 'Approve'? 'selected': '';?> >Approved</option>
              </select>
          </div>
          <input type="hidden" name="Book_No" value="<?php echo $Book_No ?>">
          <div align="center">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" onclick="submit()">Save</button>
          </div>
        </form>
```

javascript to use the bootbox

```
  <script>
    function submit() {
      bootbox.confirm({
        title: "<span style='color: white;'><b>Submit</b></span>",
        message: "Do you want to update this details?",
        buttons: {
            confirm: {
                label: 'Yes',
                className: 'btn btn-primary btn-sm'
            },
            cancel: {
                label: 'No',
                className: 'btn btn-danger btn-sm'
            }
        },
    callback: function (result) {
      if (result === true) {
            location.href = '../../dashboard/dashboard_admin.php';
        }else{

        }
    }
      });
  }
  </script>
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: you  just alert pass in javascript..can disply alert when submit button check that.

Comment: like   <script>
    function submit() {  alert(1);  your code}

Comment: can you show the example code? I not too understand